# Rectify graphviz lines

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to create a graph that looks like a lattice that keeps extending. Here's the code I have:

```
graph G {
0 [label=""];
1 [label=""];
2 [label=""];
3 [label=""];
4 [label=""];
5 [label=""];
6 [label=""];
7 [label=""];
8 [label=""];
9 [label="", shape="none"];
10 [label="", shape="none"];
11 [label="", shape="none"];
12 [label="", shape="none"];
13 [label="", shape="none"];
14 [label="", shape="none"];
15 [label="", shape="none"];
16 [label="", shape="none"];
17 [label="", shape="none"];
18 [label="", shape="none"];
19 [label="", shape="none"];
20 [label="", shape="none"];
0 -- 1;
0 -- 2;
0 -- 3;
0 -- 4;
1 -- 5;
2 -- 5;
2 -- 6;
3 -- 6;
3 -- 7;
4 -- 7;
4 -- 8;
1 -- 8;
1 -- 9;
2 -- 10;
3 -- 11;
4 -- 12;
5 -- 13;
6 -- 14;
7 -- 15;
8 -- 16;
5 -- 17;
6 -- 18;
7 -- 19;
8 -- 20;
}
```

However, this produces output like:

[image: graph]

Is there a way to get the edges on the corner nodes rectified so that it looks more regular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up adding a few more invisible vertices and invisible edges, which works. It's not the most elegant solution though.

```
graph G {
ratio="fill";
margin=0;
0 [label=""];
1 [label=""];
2 [label=""];
3 [label=""];
4 [label=""];
5 [label=""];
6 [label=""];
7 [label=""];
8 [label=""];
9 [label="", shape=none];
10 [label="", shape=none];
11 [label="", shape=none];
12 [label="", shape=none];
13 [label="", shape=none];
14 [label="", shape=none];
15 [label="", shape=none];
16 [label="", shape=none];
17 [label="", shape=none];
18 [label="", shape=none];
19 [label="", shape=none];
20 [label="", shape=none];
0 -- 1;
0 -- 2;
0 -- 3;
0 -- 4;
1 -- 5;
2 -- 5;
2 -- 6;
3 -- 6;
3 -- 7;
4 -- 7;
4 -- 8;
1 -- 8;
1 -- 9;
2 -- 10;
3 -- 11;
4 -- 12;
5 -- 13;
6 -- 14;
7 -- 15;
8 -- 16;
5 -- 17;
6 -- 18;
7 -- 19;
8 -- 20;
11 -- 18 [style=invis];
14 -- 10 [style=invis];
10 -- 17 [style=invis];
13 -- 9 [style=invis];
9 -- 16 [style=invis];
20 -- 12 [style=invis];
12 -- 15 [style=invis];
19 -- 11 [style=invis];
}
```